# Run existing Wordpress site using Docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I want to run my existing Wordpress site on Docker for local development.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    ports:
      - "9306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: example_database_name

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/html"
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example_password
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: example_database_name
```

However, the problem I have with the offical Wordpress Docker image is that it insists on installing Wordpress. This is fine if you don't have Wordpress installed, but causes a LOT of problems if already have it installed. This is especially frustrating because I organised my folders so all the internal wordpress files are in a separate folder called "wp", with "wp-content" on a separate directory.

So my question is how can I run my **existing** Wordpress site using Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet if you want to use the official image is going to be to mount the `wp-content` directory not the entire `www` directory, like:

`-v /path/to/my/blog/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content`

and adjust the custom set-up you have involving your "wp" directory. Wordpress expects a certain directory structure, so depending on why you broke out your files you may or may not be able to use the default container. The nice thing about using it this way is you can update WP simply by updating the container and all your files remain protected.

If you needs are too custom for that, as mentioned, you can try using the WP Dockerfile and edit to suit you needs, but if you can use the standard `wp-content` structure, it's going to make things simpler to manage and maintain.

Comment: Yeah I think modifying the DockerFile is the best course of action!

Answer (score 1):

With the official Wordpress image, Docker will starts a container which use Debian as base system, with apache, php and wordpress installed. If you don't like it, you can create your customized image by creating [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/). You can discard any component that you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

As a general advice, you should be able to mount your sources as a volume on paths that override existing individual files or complete directories to tailor the container to your needs.

Comment: Dosent my code already do that? The issue is that it also creates a bunch of folders that I don't use.